# Регулярное выражение с запретом на повторение подряд идущих символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь создать регулярное выражение, валидирующее следующие требования:

- Возможно одновременное использование кириллицы и цифр (без пробелов и спец. символов)
- Возможно одновременное использование латиницы и цифр (без пробелов и спец. символов)
- Невозможно одновременное использование кириллицы и латиницы
- Первая буква должна быть заглавной, не может быть цифрой
- Невозможно использование 3 и более одинаковых символов подряд
- Длина последовательности - от 2 до 16 цифр включительно

Прошу помощи по мере ваших сил, перепробовал несколько вариантов с просторов сети, сам не справился.

Comment: Уточните язык программирования или программу где будет использоваться регулярное выражение, так же неплохо было бы увидеть, какие шаблоны уже использовались

Comment: Вопрос: А почему бы не разбить это на несколько регулярок, и по очереди проверять строку?)

Comment: @PotroNik, да, конечно, прошу прощения.
Синтаксис команд Google Forms: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en

Ближайшее к моему решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973233/

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ввиду отсутствия опыта хорошо понимаю, как валидировать первый символ и "хвост" по отдельности, но не понимаю, как прикрутить к ним лимит на повторение символов, чтобы учитывался и первый, и "хвост".

Comment: Если это все описание их поддержки regexp, то вряд ли получится сделать, для PHP например сделал сейчас такой шаблон как пример https://regex101.com/r/wko9hz/1

Comment: @mainefremov попробуйте этот шаблон: `(?!.*(.)\1\1)^(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}|[А-Я][А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15})` должен сработать

Comment: @PotroNik, да, вот только в формах нет поддержки negative lookahead, чем это заменить, ума не приложу..

Comment: @mainefremov в ссылках на более подробную информацию он есть... странно получается

Comment: @mainefremov как советовал "@OPTIMUSPRIME" сделать отдельную проверку на строку

Comment: @PotroNik имеется ввиду что-то типа \1{2,}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110606/discussion-between-potronik-and-mainefremov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенесу шаблон из комментария в ответ:

```
(?!.*(.)\1\1)^(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}|[А-ЯЁ][А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15})
```

---

Рассмотрим его по частям, сначала первую группу:
`(?!.*(.)\1\1)` где `?!` - означает негативный просмотр вперед и в случае, если мы видим в строке соответствие указанному шаблону в группе, захват не происходит.
Сам шаблон выглядит так:
`.*` - ноль и более любых символов
`(.)` - обычная группа захвата (не омон конечно) она будет пронумерована как первая, в которую мы помещаем один любой символ
Подставляем символы захваченные в группу `\1\1`, т.е. ели подряд идут 3 и более символа мы их захватываем шаблоном, а негативная группа исключает данную строку

---

`^` - эта шляпа означает символ начала строки

---

Вторая группа:
`(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}|[А-Я][А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15})`
`?:` - говорит о том что группа не захватывается и мы не сможем ее вызвать далее
`[A-Z]` - Одна заглавная буква латинского алфавита в диапазоне от `A` до `Z`
`[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}` - диапазон латинских букв в любом регистре и диапазон цифр не менее одной, не более 15, с первой заглавной буквой получается от 2 до 16 символов
`|` - означает или, т.е. у нас строка или как описано выше или как описано ниже
`[А-Я]` - аналогично латинской группе, только на кирилице, кстати да, в диапазон `А-Я` не входит буква `Ё` ее нужно прописывать отдельно `[А-ЯЁ]`
`[А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15}` - аналогично группе с латинскими буквами и цифрами, только кириллица.

UPD: забыл про символ окончания строки - `$` его нужно поставить в конце шаблона